# Is the XAML Declaration and Code Behind Necessary for WPF Animations?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I'm new to WPF animations but I was curious concerning the XAML and code behind definitions for the animation.

I reviewed the following site from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

And it contains the XAML and code behind definitions for the animiation.  As depicted it appears these would clash since the XAML definition is not associated with a key.  Is that correct?  If so, is it necessary to define the animation in both the XAML and the code behind?

Sorry if this question is rudimentary but I suppose that is what self study gets ya! I recently finished an extension program and I want to learn how to add animation to my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are referring to exactly, but they probably just showed how to do the same animation in either language, only one is required.

In general almost everything you can do in XAML can be done in code, often XAML is preferable because it's declarative and nicely structured.

Comment: I second that. Most animations can be done in XAML alone which is also basically the mode of transportation when creating animations in Blend

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I was trying to clarify!